# Help: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException 12.34.56.78:60000

Tags: exception, connection, hadoop, hbase

I am writting a small Java application to connect to a HBase node. The ZooKeeper connection is successful, but later, I systematically get the following error (I have changed my IP address of course):

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException 12.34.56.78:60000
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It is running, I can access http://12.34.56.78:60010 as described in the CDH3 documentation. When I run the jps command, it shows as a process with a pid on my node...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved that issue. Before someone commits suicide... -> the problem is caused by a mismatch between the HBase.jar versions available in the central maven repository (currently 0.90.xx) and those used by Cloudera's CDH3 installation package (0.89.xx).

The main issue is that Cloudera compiles its own Hbase.jar and these are not available from the central repository. But, Cloudera makes them available from:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

To find the HBase version you need for your application, open http://your.node.ip.address:60010. For CDH3Beta3, it is 0.89.20100924-28. Then, add it in your pom.xml as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.89.20100924-28</version>
</dependency>
```

Et voila!